# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException:

Tags: java, exception, jpa, persistence

I am trying to delete records from a table using JPA Controller method, but I get the following exception..

"javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Cannot call methods requiring a transaction if the entity manager has not been joined to the current transaction."

Following is the code I am trying to run

```
 public void deleteRulesofType(String ruleType) throws NotSupportedException, SystemException, Exception {

    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        utx.begin();
        Query query = em.createQuery("delete from  RulesFound r where r.ruleType=:ruleType");
        query.setParameter("ruleType", ruleType);
        query.executeUpdate();
        em.flush();
        utx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            utx.rollback();
        } catch (Exception re) {
            throw new RollbackFailureException("An error occurred attempting to roll back the transaction.", re);
        }
        throw e;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make your entity manager to join the transaction by calling

```
em.joinTransaction();
```

Comment: Thanks @elefasGR, I removed the em.flush() line and added em.joinTransaction() and then clean and build the project. But I still get the exception when I run it :(

Comment: Can you update your code with the changes you mention please?

Comment: sorry.. my bad. I forgot to call em.joinTransaction() before query.executeUpdate();. That's why. Now it works perfect.. Thank you so much :)